# Robot framework: how to get a list from a python method that returns a list

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to get a list from the following python method through robot framework:

```
folders.py:
MAINFOLDERS = []
def get_locators():
    return MAINFOLDERS
```

and the keyword:

```
Assert main folders are in the same order
    ${MAINFOLDERS}=  folders.get_locators
```

As far as I understand, `${MAINFOLDERS}` should be a list that looks like this:

```
[
'//span[contains(text(), "AutomationTestFolder - 02 18 2022 12:54:02")]', 
'//span[contains(text(), "AutomationTestFolder - 02 18 2022 12:54:05")]'
]
```

The problem is that the output is given as `string`, not a `list`. So the actual output is `"['//span[contains(text(), "AutomationTestFolder - 02 18 2022 12:54:02")]','//span[contains(text(),"AutomationTestFolder - 02 18 2022 12:54:05")]']"`

How can I create a list out of the output of `folder.get_locators()`

Comment: Did you run your test code? It returns a list for me. You should check why your real code returns a string instead of a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: `@{MAINFOLDERS}` instead of `${MAINFOLDERS}`

```
Assert main folders are in the same order
    @{MAINFOLDERS}=  folders.get_locators
    FOR  ${F}  IN  @{MAINFOLDERS}
        log to console  F:${F}
    END
```